# obtaining outer loop value inside inner loop with xslt

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

Here is my code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/hundred">
    <div class="page_spacer" />
    <div class="page_section" style="{./style}">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="./descriptiontext" />
    <button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{./viewalllink}'"><xsl:value-of select="./label" /></button>
    <br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="./contendors/contendor">
        <img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/{../locid}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying to obtain the `locid` value from the `first loop of hundreds` and use it within the `second loop inside the img element`. I thought maybe `../locid` would insinuate using the parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind it to a variable:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/hundred">
  <xsl:variable name="h" select="."/>
    <div class="page_spacer" />
    <div class="page_section" style="{./style}">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
    <xsl:value-of select="./descriptiontext" />
    <button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{./viewalllink}'"><xsl:value-of select="./label" /></button>
    <br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="./contendors/contendor">
        <img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/{$h/locid}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```